# NavigationDrawer & KeyEvent propagation

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, keyevent, onkeydown

When in my Activity i override *onKeyDown* function to control keyback action on opened NavigationDrawer like this snippet

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        if (mLeftDrawer.isShown()) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mLeftDrawer);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

returning ***false*** instead of ***true***, where is received the resulting propagation (to up) of the event?
Thanks

Comment: in this case, you use key event but you return false. so that, some parent class can still use the key event. this can cause many side effect in your application. I think you should return true. you dont call super.onKeyDown, so returning true does not cause application go back

Comment: Thanks, I see that returning true or false in this case has the same effect. So, what can be the parent of a class Activity?

Comment: parent class, or some observer class. for instance, activity can have a scroll view, and if you return false, activity sends this key to scroll view. whenever you use a event, you have to return "true", that other (parent or siblings) objects will not use this event anymore

Comment: I think the flow is different: when the event reaches the Activity it has already been dispatched to the underlying Views and those rejected. Activity then can only propagate it upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hi GPack I do the same in my app, control keycode_back for control a little bit navigation drawer but I use a different code, like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    //Control Navigation
    //Floors level
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && ActualFragment == 0)
    {
        if(drawerMenu.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)){
            drawerMenu.closeDrawers();
        }
        else{
            RemoveAndReplaceFragment_ToFloors(getFragmentManager());
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I think this it's that you needs... Advice me if you need more help or same!!
Good luck GPack!

Comment: thanks but the question is: where is received the resulting propagation returning _false_ from _onKeyDown_?